# Erro "Can not update identity column 'order'"

Tags: python, django

Por uma necessidade antiga de um projeto, o desenvolvedor da época criou um campo na tabela que não é uma chave primária mas é auto incrementável, porém, o django retorna um erro por não conseguir atualizar esse campo. O uso do tipo AutoField do Django é destinado a chave primária, o mesmo não pode ser usado nesse caso, porém não sei se ha alguma maneira de mapear a tabela corretamente.

Exemplo de um modelo que representa a tabela video.

```
class Video(models.Model):
    id = UUIDField(db_column='ID', default=uuid.uuid4, auto=True)
    titulo = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=200, db_column='DsVideo')
    order = models.IntegerField(db_column='order')
```

O campo "order" é que esta no banco de dados esta como auto incrementável, porém ao salvar, o erro `Can not update identity column 'order'` é retornado.

Comment: @CharlesChessman agora ficou bom, pois quando vierem respostas, elas podem ajudar não apenas você, mas também outros usuários do site que não entendam inglês.

Comment: Charles, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Obrigado por traduzir sua pergunta. Desculpe qualquer atrito que você possa ter sentido, mas cada comunidade possui suas regras e o propósito desta é justamente prover conteúdo de qualidade para o público de fala portuguesa. Muitos aqui entendem Inglês, mas analogamente também não haveria resposta sobre puzzles no site sobre code review, mesmo que os mesmos usuários estejam nos dois sites. Isso é essencial pois o objetivo da rede não é apenas de solucionar problemas pontuais, mas de prover uma base de conhecimento relevante para todos. Divirta-se!

Comment: Bom dia, o problema é mais com banco do que com Django, qual banco esta usando?

Answer (score 0):

[Nessa pergunta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7158559/520779) o autor encontrou uma solução temporária, que é remover os campos problemáticos da *query* de inserção/atualização. Adaptado ao seu código:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    id = UUIDField(db_column='ID', default=uuid.uuid4, auto=True)
    titulo = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=200, db_column='DsVideo')
    order = models.IntegerField(db_column='order')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.order is not None:
            self._meta.local_fields = [f for f in self._meta.local_fields if f.name != 'order']
```

Como o próprio SGBD está responsável por atualizar esse campo, o fato do Django ignorá-lo na escrita (mas ainda te dar a opção de acessá-lo para leitura) não deve ser um problema. Nota: a pergunta é antiga (2011), não posso garantir que a técnica ainda funcione nas versões atuais do Django.